How to optimize webscraping an ASPX site with dynamically generated pop up
I have an aspx site which has a form and when you fill it a pop up occurs which has a html table i want to scrape. The pop up is dynamically generated, as in the format is www.xyz.com/something/something/"Temp"FinancialData.aspx where the temp changes when you switch months on the form. (site: https://www.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/en/data-forms/financial-data/financial-data-banks). I have code that can extract the data but it is ridiculously slow and I haven't been able to find some hidden api. Just found in the code that this simply occurs
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.open( '../Temp/79c02340-132c-4166-a5d0-f1f375e384fbFinancialData.aspx'


Hence i was hoping to optimize the code or if anyone has another way I can tackle this.
This is what I have so far.
def extract_table_data(driver, date_label, bank_code):
  
    tables = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.w100.borderspace-0.table.table-lined')
    #checking to see if two table exist
    if len(tables) < 2:
        print("Not enough tables found on the page.")
        return pd.DataFrame()
    
    #looking at second table
    target_table = tables[1]
    
   
    descriptions = ['(a) Federal and Provincial', '(b) Municipal or School Corporations',
                    '(c) Deposit-taking institutions', '(i) Tax sheltered', '(ii) Other', '(e) Other'] 
    data = []
    description_index = 0
    capture = False

    # Start iterating over rows in the target table
    for row in target_table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr'):
        row_text = row.text.strip()  # Get row text once to minimize repeated calls

        # Capturing when we find start of table
        if "1. Demand and notice deposits" in row_text:
            capture = True  # Enable data capturing
        
        if capture:
            cols = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
            if len(cols) > 1 and description_index < len(descriptions):
                # Append data for 'Total' column only (assuming it's in the second cell)
                data.append((date_label, descriptions[description_index], bank_code, cols[1].text.strip()))
                description_index += 1

            if description_index >= len(descriptions) or "2. Fixed-term deposits" in row_text:
                break  

    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Category', 'Bank Code', 'Total'])

# Main scraping function
def scrape_data(driver, bank_code, date_option):
    try:
        # Load website
        driver.get("https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/FINDAT/DTIBanks.aspx?T=0&LANG=E")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "DTIWebPartManager_gwpDTIBankControl1_DTIBankControl1_institutionTypeCriteria_type1RadioButton"))).click()

        # Select bank and date
        Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "DTIWebPartManager_gwpDTIBankControl1_DTIBankControl1_institutionTypeCriteria_institutionsDropDownList")).select_by_value(bank_code)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "DTIWebPartManager_gwpDTIBankControl1_DTIBankControl1_dtiReportCriteria_monthlyRadioButton"))).click()
        date_dropdown = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "DTIWebPartManager_gwpDTIBankControl1_DTIBankControl1_dtiReportCriteria_monthlyDatesDropDownList"))))
        date_dropdown.select_by_value(date_option)

        # Extract the formatted date for labeling
        date_label = date_dropdown.first_selected_option.text.split()
        date_label = f"{date_label[0][:3]}-{date_label[-1]}"

        # Submit form
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "DTIWebPartManager_gwpDTIBankControl1_DTIBankControl1_submitButton").click()
        time.sleep(2)

        # Switch to new window for data extraction
        main_window = driver.current_window_handle
        for handle in driver.window_handles:
            if handle != main_window:
                driver.switch_to.window(handle)
                break

        # Wait for tables to load and capture data
        WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "table")))
        return extract_table_data(driver, date_label, bank_code)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing bank {bank_code} and date {date_option}: {e}")
        return None

    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(main_window)

def main():
    date_options = generate_date_options(2024, 8, 2024, 8)
    bank_codes = ["Z005"]

    final_data, final_summary = [], []
    driver = initialize_driver()

    for bank_code in bank_codes:
        for date_option in date_options:
            print(f"Processing bank: {bank_code}, date: {date_option}")
            df = scrape_data(driver, bank_code, date_option)
            if not df.empty:
                # Accumulate data without immediately processing each DataFrame
                final_data.append(df)

    # Code for generating two tables, one detailed and one with only total
    if final_data:
        final_df = pd.concat(final_data, ignore_index=True)
        final_df['Total'] = pd.to_numeric(final_df['Total'].str.replace(',', ''), errors='coerce')  

        summary_df = final_df.groupby(['Date', 'Bank Code', 'Category'])['Total'].sum().reset_index()
        summary_df.to_csv('demand_and_notice_deposits_summary.csv', index=False)
        final_df.to_csv('demand_and_notice_deposits_detailed.csv', index=False)
        print("Scraping complete!")
    else:
        print("No data was found for any of the banks or dates.")

    driver.quit()
    return final_data, final_summary

final_data, final_summary = main()

Is there any way I can optimize this?

You should use bs4 with concurrency and this will do the job for you,
After reviewing your target web app I found this post requests https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/FINDAT/DTIBanks.aspx?T=0&LANG=E fetching your final URL (URL with UUID in it which fetching all the table data),
Sample Code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import quote
import re
import concurrent.futures

success = []

token_clean_1 = '[\=;\\"\<\>,)(]'
token_clean_2 = "[']"
session = requests.Session()

url = 'https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/FINDAT/DTIBanks.aspx?T=0&LANG=E'

def clean(result):
    cleanToken = re.sub(token_clean_1, '', result.group(0))
    return re.sub(token_clean_2, '', cleanToken)


def getInputData(content):
    body = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    event_validation = soup.find('input', id='__EVENTVALIDATION')['value'] #mandatory value
    view_state = soup.find('input', id='__VIEWSTATE')['value'] #mandatory value
    view_state_generator = soup.find('input', id='__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')['value'] #mandatory value
    date = soup.find('select', id="DTIWebPartManager_gwpDTIBankControl1_DTIBankControl1_dtiReportCriteria_monthlyDatesDropDownList").findAll('option') #get all the date value to create a list of the body for next func
    for i in date:
        data = f"__VIEWSTATE={quote(view_state, safe='')}&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR={view_state_generator}&__EVENTVALIDATION={quote(event_validation, safe='')}&DTIWebPartManager%24gwpDTIBankControl1%24DTIBankControl1%24institutionTypeCriteria%24institutionsDropDownList=Z005&DTIWebPartManager%24gwpDTIBankControl1%24DTIBankControl1%24dtiReportCriteria%24Frequency=monthlyRadioButton&DTIWebPartManager%24gwpDTIBankControl1%24DTIBankControl1%24dtiReportCriteria%24monthlyDropDownList=DTI-1&DTIWebPartManager%24gwpDTIBankControl1%24DTIBankControl1%24submitButton=Submit&DTIWebPartManager%24gwpDTIBankControl1%24DTIBankControl1%24dtiReportCriteria%24monthlyDatesDropDownList={quote(i['value'])}" #post body for next func
        body.append(data)
    return body

def getFinalUrl(data):
    url = 'https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/FINDAT/DTIBanks.aspx?T=0&LANG=E' #fetching uuid value from this endpoint
    header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:131.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/131.0"
    }
    resp = session.post(url, data=data, headers=header)
    #BS won't work on JS value so we have to switched manual with regex to get the UUID value used in table endpoint: https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/{UUID}FinancialData.aspx
    token = re.compile('[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}')
    result = re.search(token, resp.text)
    if result:
        print(f"https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/{clean(result)}FinancialData.aspx")

resp = session.get(url).text

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    future_to_url = (executor.submit(getFinalUrl, data) for data in getInputData(resp))
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            data = str(type(exc))
        finally:
            success.append(data)
            print(str(len(success)),end="\r")

#your code to get data from the table should be here

Sample Output (your final URL to get the data from the table):
https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/8b65b060-28fe-44d4-add8-eee35c63e2b6FinancialData.aspx
https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/7495b67f-baa4-485c-b4ef-bed47ebecaeeFinancialData.aspx
https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/9fd9e535-eee2-443f-88fa-61c4e2572a24FinancialData.aspx
https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/c4182c43-89ab-4b2b-b8c1-dd60987b327aFinancialData.aspx
https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/96889b37-56bc-47ee-b249-a5cec351687bFinancialData.aspx
https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/46258b8e-5859-436b-8d6d-1a15e3a5d529FinancialData.aspx
https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/7109991e-4099-4efc-a70d-14b9d3a2d16dFinancialData.aspx
https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/bcd70227-e23c-4e01-ab45-7e7f83dddc6fFinancialData.aspx
https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/4748e8ac-b8b1-45bb-8ee9-507c1d5da787FinancialData.aspx
https://ws1ext.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/65fdff2b-de7e-4a3a-8965-d3745b87e5ccFinancialData.aspx

Please add your code to fetch the value from the table like you did in extract_table_data function
Let me know if this is helpful for you
